# VS2017 TypeScript error: Duplicate identifier 'URLs'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

We have a Visual Studio 2017 project containing some TypeScript files.  In several places we have a `URLs` class whose implementation varies so we can change the site URLs based on which file we pull in, like:

**customer/urls.ts**

```
namespace Portal {
    export class URLs {
        static homePage(): string { return "/customer"; }
    }
}
```

**supplier/urls.ts**

```
namespace Portal {
    export class URLs {
        static homePage(): string { return "/supplier"; }
    }
}
```

However, this causes Visual Studio 2017 to give the error "Duplicate identifier 'URLs'".  VS seems to assume that all TypeScript files will get pulled in to the webpage but since only one of these will get pulled in for any given page, there won't actually be a duplicate identifier in the browser.  How can I stop VS giving this error (or is there actually a good reason for it)?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a combination of two things:

1. Namespaces in Typescript (also called "internal modules"), by definition, pollute the global namespace. When a file starts with a non-exported namespace declaration, it means that identifier is going to be available globally. This is to be contrasted with modules (also called "external modules"), which must be imported and exported explicitly. See [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8004#issuecomment-208320871) for a good explanation.
2. Unless you are explicitly including or excluding specific files in your `tsconfig.json`, both definitions for `Portal.URLs` are going to be included. From the [`tsconfig.json` documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler
>   defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in
>   the containing directory and subdirectories except those excluded
>   using the "exclude" property.

So, the compiler is trying to add the same declaration to the global namespace twice, causing your duplicate identifier error.

The right fix depends on how you're using this class and how the decision is made as to which implementation to use.

One fix would be to avoid namespaces altogether. You could, for example, define a `URLs` interface, import that wherever needed, and then use a `CustomerURLs` implementation or `SupplierURLs` implementation based on some environment variable or build configuration.

Another option would be to create a base `tsconfig.json` and then use `extends` to create separate `tsconfig.customer.json`, `tsconfig.supplier.json`, etc. files for each configuration. In each one, you would exclude all `**/urls.ts` except the one you care about. However, this is not particularly scalable, and I'm not sure how VS would handle it from an intellisense perspective.

Comment: It's complaining about the URLs class being exported, not the Portal namespace.

Comment: Starting a file with `namespace Portal` means 1) that a global namepspace `Portal` is going to exist, and 2) that every exported member in the file will be in that global namespace. So in this case, `export class URLs` means "make `URLs` available globally under `Portal.URLs`," as opposed to "make `URLs` importable in another file" (which is what a module export does). Counterintuitively, if you export the _namespace_ (`export namespace Portal`), the problem will go away, but then it won't be available globally, which I imagine is what you are going for.